# Отложенная отправка сообщения в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telebot, schedule

Требуется отправлять через бот сообщение в заданное время и с заданными промежутками. Думаю из кода будет ясно:

```
def schedule_delay(message, time):
   delay = message.text
   schedule.every().day.at(time).do(delay_set(message, delay))


def delay_set(message, delay):
   schedule.every(delay).minutes.do(job(message))


def job(message):
   bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, content_manage.pic_random())
```

Думаю библиотека schedule не предназначена для работы с аргументами из-за чего и возникает проблема.
С такой реализацией бот сразу же выполняет функцию job, а не в заданное время, затем просто крашится.

Библиотека schedule крутится в отдельном от библиотеки PyTelegramBotApi потоке. Думаю из-за этого тоже система ведёт себя нестабильно.
Бота можно было бы построить и встроенными в API функциями отложенных сообщений, но от бота требуется отправка сообщений в каналы.